# Why does this not print "super"?

Tags: java, polymorphism

I have this code:

```
public class Superclass {

    public void print() {
        System.out.println("super");
    }
}

public class Subclass extends Superclass {

    public void print() {
        System.out.println("sub");
    }
}
```

And then this:

```
Subclass obj4 = new Subclass();
((Superclass) obj4).print();
```

I would think that the above print statement prints "super," since it is cast to Superclass, but this is not the case - it prints "sub". Why is this?

Comment: You need to google what polymorphism/late binding is.

Comment: you can't up cast like that, it is just how it is, the object is a `SubClass`

Comment: Also please dont put spaces inside the parentheses of no parameter functions. It bugs me :(

Comment: @Dgrin: Is that not a Java convention?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The upcasting of the type doesn't make any different. Which `toString()` to call is determined by the runtime type of the **instance**, not the reference.

Since `Subclass` overrode `Superclass`'s toString, invoking any `Subclass` instance will always resolve to `Subclass`'s toString.

```
Object obj = new Subclass();
obj.toString();  // will still return "sub"
```

Comment: Actually `Subclass` overrides `print()` not `toString()` method. Anyway +1.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you didn't call super.print(). By default, subclass's method overrides superclass's one, no matter what casting you make

```
public class Subclass extends Superclass { 

   public void print () { 
       super.print();
       System.out.println ("sub"); 
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are implicitly overriding the method in your subclass.

If you have used C# before, this might be confusing, because Java does not need an override keyword to override methods. Java automatically overrides methods with the same signature.

You might see the `@Override` annotation on methods, but that's just a safeguard to ensure that you're actually overriding something (it prevents typos and such); it does not actually impact your program itself.

Answer (score 1):

Typecasting an object doesn't change the object itself. It basically helps you to access the fields / methods which are part of the contract of the class you typecast an object reference to.
Let's say your Subclass had this definition:

```
public class Subclass extends Superclass { 

  public void print ( ) { 
    System.out.println ("sub"); 
  } 

  public void subClassMethod()
  {
    //do something
  }
}
```

And you create an object of type Subclass but hold the reference using a Superclass variable:
`Superclass obj4 = new Subclass ();`

Now obj4 gives you access only to the contract for Superclass so you cannot call obj4.subClassMethod() which will give you a compile time error.

In this case you will typecast it to Subclass to get access to the subClassMethod:
`((Subclass)obj4).subClassMethod()`

Answer (score 0):

If you are overriding a method from a superclass you need to include the **@Override** notation in your sub class.
Also if you want to use the print() method of the super class,in your subclass's print() method you can use `super.print();` im 100% that will work.